# How do I select the option inside a dropdown by Python Selenium that's an href?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to build a simple scraper to load the location addresses that are in three different areas (within the dropdown  values) then copy all those addresses as text. I've managed to use python Selenium to load the website in Chrome and click the link (which there is an dynamic number that changes every time the website loads. Now it says 2801157, but will change every time). But after clicking the dropdown, I don't know why I can't click those option values (i.e. Hong Kong Island, Kowloon, New Territories inside the "li" one at a time). The html section hidden is under many divs; the relevant section is as below:

```
<div class="hkoutlettop_select">
  <select name="" class="hkoutlet_select selDistrict" tabindex="1" sb="28011577" style="display: none;">
    <option value="Hong Kong Island">Hong Kong Island</option>
    <option value="Kowloon">Kowloon</option>
    <option value="New Territories">New Territories</option>
  </select>
  <div id="sbHolder_28011577" class="sbHolder" tabindex="1">
    <a id="sbToggle_28011577" href="#" class="sbToggle sbToggleOpen"></a><a id="sbSelector_28011577" href="#" class="sbSelector">Hong Kong Island</a>
    <ul id="sbOptions_28011577" class="sbOptions" style="top: 22px; max-height: 715px;">
      <li><a href="#Hong Kong Island" rel="Hong Kong Island" class="">Hong Kong Island</a></li>
      <li><a href="#Kowloon" rel="Kowloon" class="">Kowloon</a></li>
      <li><a href="#New Territories" rel="New Territories" class="">New Territories</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is my code

```
# loading Chrome browswer, add useragent options
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)

# wait a random amount of seconds. random_time is a list of integers
driver.implicitly_wait(random_time)

# the restaurant's website
driver.get(url)

# This gets the dynamic id
WebElement_Dynamic_ID_selector = driver.find_element_by_class_name("sbSelector").get_attribute("id")

# This gets the dynamic id, not sure if I need to do this though
WebElement_Dynamic_ID_options = driver.find_element_by_class_name("sbOptions").get_attribute("id")

# select dropdown once it is available
district_dropdown = WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, WebElement_Dynamic_ID_selector)))

# click dropdown
district_dropdown.click()

# wait for areas to show up
area_list_dropdown = WebDriverWait(driver,100).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID,WebElement_Dynamic_ID_options)))

# I'm stuck
```

Comment: Can you provide the link to the website? It's usually find the class of the dropdowns, loop over them and `click` the one you want to

Comment: Hi ThatBird, the website is this https://ssl.fairwood.com.hk/eng/main/hkoutlets.jsp

I'm learning as much as I can, did lots of trial and errors, but still getting nowhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use below solution:

```
driver.get(url)
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "sbSelector"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Kowloon"))).click()
```

Comment: Oh, that line 
EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Kowloon"))).click() worked for me.

Thanks Andersson

Answer (score 0):

Try to change locator for `WebElement_Dynamic_ID_options`:

```
WebElement_Dynamic_ID_options = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//ul[@class='sbOptions']/li/a")
for values in WebElement_Dynamic_ID_options:
    values.click() //or any action you need
```

Comment: Hi Sergiy, I've changed the locator as above and I just tried print(values) to see what it was loading. And its loading 10 different WebElements.

<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="a4e21dd58c5c6c137f8ea23cc7bc4143", element="0.04313009080139185-10")>

Not sure why. But Andersson helped me with this, but I'll still play around with yours. Thank you!